# Is it possible to wikify Visual Studio XML comments?

Tags: visual-studio, wiki, xml-comments

Is it possible to generate a set of wiki pages from XML comment file generated by Visual Studio?

I'm talking about something like Sandcastle, but for wiki format instead of compiled CHM.

Edit: I'm using MediaWiki which can import/export articles in XML. So I hope that it is possible to write a transformation converting XML comments to MediaWiki XML.

Comment: As in a one time migration from inline XML to MediaWiki XML? Because I don't see how you are going to keep both in sync if you are going to keep the inline XML comments AND allow users to edit the MediaWiki.

Comment: Wiki pages with technical documentation should not be edited by users except core classes developed years ago and not going to be changed anymore. There are general articles describing classes and their usage, I just want to add a link to detailed programming reference.

Comment: What do you gain by having it in a wiki? The main benefit of a wiki is that it is easily editable. However, you're not intending to actually ever edit the pages manually. It really sounds like the best approach is just to not use a wiki and directly place the files on the server in a folder near the wiki.

Comment: The most important things that I wnat to get using wiki:
1) Discussions. I cannot discuss static html files generated by Doxygen or Sandcastle.
2) Better integration with general project documentation which is stored in wiki.

Comment: Please check out my comment. I suspect you're actually thinking about MediaWiki & API reference integration, and I just posted a solution for this.

Comment: I had the same problem and saw this post.  So, I created the CS2Wiki.awk script to translate my libraries XML files. The AWK scripts is a hack and got me 70% of the way to creating the MediaWiki file. [CS2Wiki.awk](https://github.com/PHuhn/NSG.Library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend a bit different solution:

- Use [Help Server](http://www.x-tensive.com/Products/HS/) to publish .CHM/.HxS on the web
- Use [special MediaWiki templates](http://wiki.dataobjects.net/index.php?title=Code_templates) to link reference from Wiki like [here](http://wiki.dataobjects.net/index.php?title=Entities,_keys_and_hierarchies).
- Use `<see href="...">` to link Wiki pages from XML comments
- See also: [FiXml](http://wiki.dataobjects.net/index.php?title=FiXml)

This is not exactly what you wanted, but I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. This is not the complete solution I was looking for, but it is much more useful than pointless doxygen answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the items mentioned above do not suffice, have you tried to simply build your own XSLT transform into the wiki markup of your choice?

You can write a simple application in .NET (or pick your platform of choice) to transform the doc XML format to wiki XML format. You'd still have to keep the wiki updated with the output files manually.

Comment: Yep, it should work. But it requires time and human resources which I do not have atm.